# How to configure mongo to use different volumes for databases?

Tags: mongodb

I see that mongo has the configuration option storage.directoryPerDB. But I only see storage.dbPath to specify which path data is stored.

We have 2 small frequently used "settings" databases that will be stored locally in the default location.  There is another "results" database for large image files, that will be written often, but queried infrequently, which has a dedicated SSD drive for its storage, this data needs to be on is own drive because our application can generate hundreds of gigs of image data in a small amount of time.

How can I configure mongod to store a database on a different drive?  The server is running on windows, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind.   The documentation at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.directoryPerDB explains how to do it perfectly.

Along with http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753321.aspx#BKMK_CMD
which describes how to mount a drive to a folder location.